# Unable to run html5 application in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

```
     I created one html5 application and generated  war file and deployed it into tomcat server . 

    After that I tried to use tomcat url  to run in android emulator, but it is not working .      Showing that webpage is not available.

    Can you please help on this issue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are locally deployed your application in tomcat. so you need to give your ip like

http://ip:8080/html5app.

it'll run your web native app in android emulator..